# A value that is initially undefined has cumbersome initialization syntax

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

`let assignment: AssignmentEntity | undefined = undefined;`

I find it rather annoying to write `undefined` twice. However, neither of them can be omitted. The first `undefined` is needed since it is part of the type and the second value is needed for the initial value.

Is there any acceptable way to write this in a shorter form?

Comment: You could skip the `= undefined` part as it is a default.

Comment: What stops you from just writing `let assignment: AssignmentEntity;` in the first place? There is a caveat of  "Variable is used before being assigned" when you do that, of course, but

Comment: and if you do not expect to perform the assignment later, then Aleksey's advice is the way to go - the compiler just needs to know that the variable `assignment` can hold either the `AssignmentEntity` or `undefined` - since it is declared with `let`, there is no need for assigning it to an explicit `undefined`.

Comment: @AlekseyL. You're right. I was sure for some reason that that would cause a TSC error of "Variable is used before being assigned" but I guess I was daydreaming since removing it works fine too. Thanks!

Comment: @VitalyB - thankfully, it is only caused by trying to check for `undefined` if the variable is not expected to hold `undefined` as a possible type (admittedly, the error could be more specific in such cases, but oh well)

Comment: @OlegValter noted. Thanks!

Comment: @AlekseyL. If you want, write your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no initial value is specified on declaration, the variable is initialized with a value of `undefined`. So in this case you can skip the initialization:

```
let assignment: AssignmentEntity | undefined;
```

https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this way:

```
type Maybe<T> = T | undefined;

class AssignmentEntity {
    foo = "bar"
}

let assignment: Maybe<AssignmentEntity>;

assignment.foo; // Object assignment is possibly 'undefined'
```

And probably better too than using a Javascript function